# apt-get source xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, mouse-event

Пробую следовать [этой](http://blog.guntram.de/?p=16) инструкции, написанной для Ubuntu 14.04. У меня 16.04. Застрял на первой же команде.

```
$ apt-get source xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'xserver-xorg-input-evdev' as source package instead of 'xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev'
E: Unable to find a source package for xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, прямо к тексту вопроса вывод команды `grep -r deb-src /etc/apt/sources.list*`. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Нужно было поставить галочку на SourceCode в Software&Updates